# How to get String to time in PreferenceActivity??

Tags: android, time, alarmmanager, preferenceactivity

I have a time picker in preference activity. I want to get the time selected using the Time Picker to be used with an Alarm. I used onPreferenceChanged to get the time but now I'm unable to pass the same to the Alarm. Here is what I have done so far.

```
tprfrnc.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
//newValue is the time i get using the time picker.it is in 24hr format. eg:23:10
String t1=newValue.toString();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try{
 Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(t1);
}catch (ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 5000;

Intent i2 = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
AlarmManager alrm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alrm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1, i2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the time to your pending intent using intent's **getExtras** `Bundle`. For example:

```
i2.putExtra("my_time", time.longValue());
```

On the other side, when you receive the broadcast, simply retrieve the time as below:

```
long time = intent.getLongExtra("my_time");
```

Comment: no its not like that.. i want to replace the long "time" with the time i receive through the"newValue". how can i do it.? i already stored  the newValue in a string "t1". but i want it to be used with the alrm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1, i2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

Comment: Just parse your **newValue** to `long` and use it the way you want.

Comment: i tried it.. but its not working.. how can i use it to set alarm? can you show me the syntax?

Comment: i parsed it to long, but im getting a stopped working error

Comment: it would be convenient if you also post error stacks